# Geoserver printing (2.8) fails: InvalidValueException

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu, printing, mapfish

I have followed this well-known sequence to use the Geoserver printing module:

```
cd /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
sudo wget http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.6.x/geoserver-2.6.x-latest-war.zip
sudo unzip geoserver-2.6.x-latest-war.zip geoserver.war
cd /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib
sudo wget http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.6.x/ext-latest/geoserver-2.6-SNAPSHOT-printing-plugin.zip
sudo unzip geoserver-2.6-SNAPSHOT-printing-plugin.zip
sudo service tomcat7 restart
Go to the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR (/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data) and a new folder called printing should be present, with config.yaml inside.
```

But I use 2.8 versions. `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json` produces the right specs:

```
{"scales":[{"name":"1:25,000","value":"25000.0"},{"name":"1:50,000","value":"50000.0"},{"name":"1:100,000","value":"100000.0"},{"name":"1:200,000","value":"200000.0"},{"name":"1:500,000","value":"500000.0"},{"name":"1:1,000,000","value":"1000000.0"},{"name":"1:2,000,000","value":"2000000.0"},{"name":"1:4,000,000","value":"4000000.0"}],"dpis":[{"name":"75","value":"75"},{"name":"150","value":"150"},{"name":"300","value":"300"}],"outputFormats":[{"name":"pdf"}],"layouts":[{"name":"A4 portrait","map":{"width":440,"height":483},"rotation":true},{"name":"Legal","map":{"width":440,"height":483},"rotation":false}],"printURL":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf","createURL":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/create.json"}
```

I use LinuxMint Rebecca (14.04 if I'm right), I read somewhere that Tomcat has some permissions issues, therefore I used from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272666/tomcat7-bind-to-port-80-fails-in-ubuntu-14-04lts):

```
sudo apt-get install authbind
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
sudo chown tomcat7 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

However, using the default config.yaml I get:

```
Error while generating PDF:
org.mapfish.print.InvalidValueException: url has an invalid value: http://geoserver.org/img/geoserver-logo.png
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.createImage(PDFUtils.java:668)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.createImageChunk(PDFUtils.java:656)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.createImageChunk(PDFUtils.java:653)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.ImageBlock.render(ImageBlock.java:66)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.createCell(PDFUtils.java:624)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.buildTable(PDFUtils.java:609)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.ColumnsBlock.render(ColumnsBlock.java:72)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.createCell(PDFUtils.java:624)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.buildTable(PDFUtils.java:609)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.HeaderFooter.render(HeaderFooter.java:55)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks.addFooter(PDFCustomBlocks.java:134)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFCustomBlocks.onEndPage(PDFCustomBlocks.java:89)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(PdfDocument.java:911)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.newPage(Document.java:363)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Page.render(Page.java:63)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.MainPage.render(MainPage.java:63)
    at org.mapfish.print.config.layout.Layout.render(Layout.java:59)
    at org.mapfish.print.output.AbstractOutputFormat.doPrint(AbstractOutputFormat.java:30)
    at org.mapfish.print.output.PdfOutputFactory.print(PdfOutputFactory.java:58)
    at org.mapfish.print.MapPrinter.print(MapPrinter.java:173)
    at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doCreatePDFFile(MapPrinterServlet.java:366)
    at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.createAndGetPDF(MapPrinterServlet.java:166)
    at org.mapfish.print.servlet.MapPrinterServlet.doGet(MapPrinterServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Circular redirect to 'http://geoserver.org:80/img/geoserver-logo.png'
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.handleImageLoadError(PDFUtils.java:357)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.loadImageFromUrl(PDFUtils.java:341)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.getImageDirect(PDFUtils.java:182)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.getImage(PDFUtils.java:102)
    at org.mapfish.print.PDFUtils.createImage(PDFUtils.java:666)
    ... 109 more
```

What would be the problem here?

Software installed:

```
ii  libtomcat7-java                             7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3                                   all          Servlet and JSP engine -- core libraries
ii  tomcat7                                     7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3                                   all          Servlet and JSP engine
ii  tomcat7-admin                               7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3                                   all          Servlet and JSP engine -- admin web applications
ii  tomcat7-common                              7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3                                   all          Servlet and JSP engine -- common files
ii  tomcat7-docs                                7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3                                   all          Servlet and JSP engine -- documentation
ii  tomcat7-examples                            7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3                                   all          Servlet and JSP engine -- example web applications

This GeoServer instance is running version 2.8.0. For more information please contact the administrator.
```

---

After testing Iant's answer I get:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "spec.json", this makes an empty POST.
```

What I did was:

```
gery@gery ~ $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @spec.json http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf > print.pdf
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "spec.json", this makes an empty POST.
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time    Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9379    0  9379    0     0   384k      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
```

--:--:-- 398k

Comment: Does that image exist? Try removing the reference to it.

Comment: the image exists, that's the weird thing

Comment: I found that `/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver` contains `mapfish-print2446310071355869802.pdf.printout` (mapfish-print2446310071355869802.pdf.printout: PDF document, version 1.5
) which is a PDF file (not completed afaik), also found that in the `geoserver.log` appears a WARN before PDF generation failed: 2015-11-14 14:38:31,935 WARN [servlet.BaseMapServlet] - Cannot delete file:/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/geoserver/wicket-filestore

Comment: After deleting this *.pdf.printout file, I re-run the creation of PDF and the same *.pdf.printout appeared, why is that?

Comment: may be you have a template issue

Comment: @iant thanks for the idea, how could I know that?

Comment: what is in your spec?

Answer (score 2):

I can't recreate your issue though I'm using GeoServer 2.7.2 which might matter.

If I install GeoServer and add the matching print extension, I can then do:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @spec.json http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf > print.pdf
```

when spec.json contains the following:

```
{"pages":[
{
  "center":[-98,36],
  "mapTitle":"Map title",
  "comment":"Some comments", 
  "scale": 4000000.0,
  "rotation":"0"
}
],"dpi":"75","units":"degrees","srs":"EPSG:4326","layers":[
{
  "baseURL":"http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
  "opacity":1,
  "singleTile":false,
  "customParams":{},
  "type":"WMS",
  "layers":["basic"],
  "format":"image/png",
  "styles":[],
  "overview":true
},
{
  "baseURL":"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?",
  "opacity":1,
  "singleTile":true,
  "customParams":{"TRANSPARENT":true},
  "type":"WMS",
  "layers":["topp:states"],
  "format":"image/png",
  "styles":[],
  "overview":false
}
],
  "layout":"A4 portrait"}
```

and I've modified the default config.yaml file to point to a local logo and added `vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org` to the list of permitted hosts using:

```
- !dnsMatch
    host: vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org
    port: 80
```

and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got `Warning: Couldn't read data from file "spec.json", this makes an empty POST.`, what does it mean? I mean, is a software piece missing?

Comment: did you install geoserver with the web archive (i.e., geoserver.war)? perhaps that would be my issue? I updated my post and put what I have installed related to geoserver.

Comment: you have to have a file called "spec.json" for curl to send to the server, see the example I gave in the answer.

Comment: ok, I did and it didn't give any warnings, but this outputs when I open it: `mupdf print.pdf 
error: cannot recognize version marker
warning: trying to repair broken xref
error: cannot find page -1 in page tree
mupdf: warning: Cannot load page
Segmentation fault`. Moreover, it says `Segmentation fault` when I click on the opened pdf.

Comment: try upgrading to GeoServer 2.7 or 2.8 (though it should be ok) and make sure you have matched the extension to GS Version exactly

Comment: if it works for you, it should work for me, I'll install 2.7 as you did, you installed with the web archive? how did you install geoserver?

Comment: I'm using Jetty but it makes no difference